# PowerBI: Timestamp in the reports and dashboard do not match

Tags: r, report, powerbi, dashboard

I have an R script which scraps tweets for a specified interval. The timestamp returned matches my current local time. 
- I created a streaming dataset and pushed these tweets to power BI pro using their REST API.
- But when I use historical data and create a report, **there is a difference in time stamp that gets displayed in the graph**. Is there a setting that I have to change within Power BI?

[image]

The left is the graph created in the dashboard (showing current local time) and right is the report which I tried to create (shows a different time stamp) and pinned it to the dashboard. (Its just one data point I have shown here)

**UPDATE:**
Pasting the report showing the data table (left is the plot from dashboard, right is the report pinned to it)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not change anything. The tile in your dashboard just shows you the most recent data (received last hour), while the one in the report shows what is received in general. In this case, it looks like you successfully received only one row (at 3:26:59 PM). If you add a table to visualize your data next to the chart, it should show only one row. Such a table will help you during the development of your solution.

Comment: I am missing something here. I run my script to receive just one data point, which was at '2018-11-06T10:26:59-0500' (i.e. 10.26 a.m). In this case, shouldn't the report also show the same timestamp? Yes, I have set the filters to show the top 100 tweets, but in this case, I have only one data point.

Comment: Please remove all filters, place a table visual to show the data in the report and publish it here. This should make it clear what are the contents of the report.

Comment: Edited the question and image of the table, pls check

Comment: It looks like it's a mix between UTC and local times. As far as I understood, it is "by design". Probably you can tweak something in the process of posting the data to the streaming dataset. Are you sending the datetime in UTC (with Z at the end of the json)? If so, try to remove the Z suffix (or add it?). If this doesn't solve the issue, you may have to think for some conversion of the time zone.